# How to include only some modules in f2py via setup.py

Tags: python, distutils, f2py

I have a very long piece of fortran code, some parts of which I would like to expose to python. It works fine from the command line, with

```
f2py -m extrpsf -c extract_psf.f95 only: extract_psf psfmany :
```

I'm hoping to distribute this, so am trying to get it to work with numpy.distutils.core.  I thought the following should work:

```
from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name="extrpsf",
ext_modules=[Extension(name='extrpsf', sources=['extract_psf.f95'],
                       f2py_options=['only: extract_psf psfmany :'])])
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Any suggestions?

Sorry for not having given details about the error message before. I now did what I should have done before and simplified the problem.  So, assume I have the following fortran code add_test.f95
    subroutine add_axis2(in, n1, n2, out)
      integer, intent(in) :: n1, n2
      double precision, intent(in) :: in(n1, n2)
      double precision, intent(out) :: out(n2)
      integer :: i2
      do i2 = 1,n2
         out(i2) = sum(in(:,i2))
      enddo
      return
    end subroutine add_axis2

```
subroutine add_axis1(in, n1, n2, out)
  integer, intent(in) :: n1, n2
  double precision, intent(in) :: in(n1, n2)
  double precision, intent(out) :: out(n1)
  integer :: i1
  do i1 = 1,n1
     out(i1) = sum(in(i1,:))
  enddo
  return
end subroutine add_axis1
```

Then, if I run

```
f2py -m add_test -c add_test.f95 only: add_axis1 :
```

I get a add_test.so, which, if I import it, only has add_axis1. However, if I make a setup.py with

```
from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name="add_test",
      ext_modules=[Extension(name='add_test', sources=['add_test.f95'],
                             f2py_options=['only: add_axis2 :'])])
```

and run

```
python setup.py build
```

the resulting add_test.so still has both subroutines. (This also explains the error message I get earlier; there are parts in my longer code that f2py chokes on, which in the manual f2py invocation simply get skipped). So, I guess my question has simplified to how I ensure in the setup.py that only some routines get made.

Looking in more detail at the output, I see that

```
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "add_test" sources
f2py options: ['only: add_axis2 :']
f2py:> build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/add_testmodule.c
creating build
creating build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'only: add_axis2 :'. Skipping file "only: add_axis2 :".
```

so the error is becoming clearer.
...
and indeed, with this some further googling gives the answer; from
http://cens.ioc.ee/pipermail/f2py-users/2005-July/001125.html
if I do instead

```
from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name="add_test",
      ext_modules=[Extension(name='add_test', sources=['add_test.f95'],
                             f2py_options=['only:']+['add_axis2']+[':'])])
```

the simple example works, and with a similar change the more complicated one works too...

Comment: Why it didn't work? What was the error?

Comment: Triggered by your question, I did what I should have done in the first place: make a simpler example.  As shown in the edited example, this allowed me to troubleshoot and find the answer. Thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

Great, the solution with using `f2py_options` works!

```
Extension(
    name='module.routine_ext',
    sources=['src/source_file.f'],
    f2py_options=['only:', 'subroutine_name', ':'],
    language='f77')
```